# Access point as a Wifi repeater for WPA2-Enterprise network

Tags: pi-3, wifi, pi-3b+, access-point

So this is a little bit of a random question but I'm attempting to follow [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-repeater-optional-with-bridge) tutorial to set up a wifi repeater with my Raspberry Pi 3B+.

I can get the Raspberry Pi to generate a network that can accept connections.

The problem I run into is getting the client connection to successfully connect to the original network due to the fact that the original network is configured using WPA2-Enterprise.

I can get the Raspberry Pi to connect to the WPA2-Enterprise network by doing the following:

Editing `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` with:

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
      ssid="MainNetworkSSID"
      scan_ssid=1
      key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
      pairwise=CCMP TKIP
      group=CCMP TKIP
      eap=PEAP
      identity="MyUsername"
      password="MyPassword"
      phase1="peapver=0"
      phase2="MSCHAPV2"
}
```

And editing `/etc/network/interfaces` with:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        pre-up wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
        post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
```

But when I go to set up the repeater it wont connect to the original network. I tried using the edits I made to `wpa_supplicant.conf` in `wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf` but this didn't seem to help. The Enterprise network does not require any certificates to join so I think it should be possible in theory, but I may be wrong. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I still could not get systemd-networkd to connect to the main network no matter the driver that was being used. I did find another solution entirely, however, that seems to have worked. I installed this modified ubuntu-mate image that supports the 3B+ and then used the built-in hotspot function on ubuntu to generate the access point. Ubuntu-mate image: https://downloads.ubiquityrobotics.com/pi.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested a WPA2-Enterprise connection because I haven't one but for my understanding it should make no difference to build a wifi repeater as far as you can establish the connection. So I suggest first to configure and test the connection with `systemd-networkd`. When it is running then you can do the next steps to combine it with the access point.

Because we use `systemd-networkd` we have to do all with it. *Networking* and *dhcpcd* is completely switched off. This is done with [Step 1: setup systemd-networkd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866) but without installing *hostapd* at this step:

```
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
# enable persistent journaling, useful for troubleshooting
rpi ~# mkdir -p /var/log/journal
rpi ~# systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal #ignore warnings (*)

# disable debian networking and dhcpcd
rpi ~# systemctl mask networking.service
rpi ~# systemctl mask dhcpcd.service
rpi ~# sudo mv /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces~
rpi ~# sed -i '1i resolvconf=NO' /etc/resolvconf.conf

# enable systemd-networkd
rpi ~# systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
rpi ~# ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

<sup>**(*) You will get one or two confusing warnings "...Cannot set file attribute..." This are not errors and doesn't matter in this case.**</sup>

Then setup wpa_supplicant for client connection with:

```
rpi ~# cat >/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="MainNetworkSSID"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    eap=PEAP
    identity="MyUsername"
    password="MyPassword"
    phase1="peapver=0"
    phase2="MSCHAPV2"
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
rpi ~# systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

This will setup *wpa_supplicant* the same way you have done with Debian *networking*. The `pre-up` you have done in `/etc/network/interfaces` you will find at line `ExecStart=` with:

```
rpi ~# systemctl cat wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

Your `post-down` is managed by *systemd* automagically. To compare:

```
pre-up wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-%I.conf -Dnl80211,wext -i%I
```

`%I` is expanded to **wlan0**. Don't use option `-B` in `ExecStart=` because the service is already running in the background. Recommended driver is `nl80211` so it is set at the first position with option `-Dnl80211,wext` so I would try it first. If you really need only the old driver `wext` then you can set `-Dwext` with:

```
rpi ~# systemctl --full edit wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

Now we have to setup the interface **wlan0**:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
# If you need a static ip address toggle commenting next three lines (example)
DHCP=yes
#Address=192.168.10.60/24
#Gateway=192.168.10.1
# Optional: if you want to connect to your own DNS server, set it here (example)
#DNS=192.168.10.10 8.8.8.8
EOF
```

Now reboot and you should have a wifi client connection. If not then you have first to fix it before going on to configure the access point and combine it with the client connection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I still could not get systemd-networkd to connect to the main network no matter the driver that was being used. I did find another solution entirely, however, that seems to have worked. I installed this modified ubuntu-mate image that supports the 3B+ and then used the built-in hotspot function on ubuntu to generate the access point. Ubuntu-mate image: [link](https://downloads.ubiquityrobotics.com/pi.html)

Comment: @DailyRPG Please make an answer to your solution. Only accecpting an answer with a click on the tick on its left side will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.